# Does pre-rolls ads play on embedded video through react native?

Tags: youtube-api

There's few recent informations about this topic and I need to be aware before I develop my next project.

I want to display youtube videos in my react native app but I need to be sure that content creators will have their ads in pre-roll forms. It's a very important matter for my app because I don't want creators to be injured by it : they need to get revenue if someone watch their video into my app.

So will it be the case ? I can't actually get any kind of pre-roll ads in my prototype...(no autoplay, full player displayed)

I also have a subsequent question about adMob on my app. If I display rewarded video in another 'Activity' (one without any youtube video displayed) after video, do you think that it's an infringment to the api policy ?

Thank's a lot for your futur help.